# how to send multiple values from single checkbox in loop

Tags: php, checkbox

Hi I'm pretty new to PHP I need help with this small form I've made on my page.

I have a single checkbox which is in a loop. I seem to get only a single checkbox value passed. Here's my form and php code:

Form:

```
<?php if($show_captions) { 
     $pic_path=$album."/".$caption;
?>
     <div class="caption" align="center">
     <form name="store" id="str" action="store.php" method="get">
     <input type="checkbox" name="pic[]" value="<?php echo $pic_path ?>"/>
     </form>
     </div>

<?php } ?>
```

store.php:

```
<?php
$path=$_GET['pic'];
if(isset($_GET['pic']))
{
    foreach($path as $pic){
    echo $pic;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: i have a submit button jus forgot to put it here its sumwher else on my page :)

Comment: oops sry...the thing is i got arnd 4 if condition in it...its pretty big...i jus want to knw if its possible to get multiple values from that one checkbox..i have this gallery and each pic has a check box...the var $pic_path has the path for each one but i seem to get only path of a single pic when i select mutiple ones

Comment: @user3152069 1) Why not, and 2) No they aren't, his names are perfectly valid.

Comment: Also, I don't see a loop here exactly.

Comment: @user3649792 It's probably because each of your checkbox is wrapped in a different `<form>`. You need to put all your checkboxes in between 1 `<form></form>` tags.

Comment: @I Can Has Kittenz thanks a lot that ws the problem!! :)i gave the <form> outside the loop and it worked